# Defining search rules in elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

How can I combine these two queries so I can search by name, publisher with one type of rules and ean by different set of rules, all in one query?

```
          'must'=> [
                [
                    "multi_match" => [
                        "query" => $this->builder->query,
                        "fields" => ['name', 'publisher', 'platform'],
                        "fuzziness" => 'auto',
                        "prefix_length" => 1,
                    ],

                    "match" => [
                        "query" => $this->builder->query,
                        "fields" => ['ean'],
                        "prefix_length" => 1
                    ],
                ]
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to solve my problem

```
           'should'=> [
                [
                    "multi_match" => [
                        "query" => $this->builder->query,
                        "fields" => ['name', 'publisher', 'platform'],
                        "fuzziness" => 'auto',
                        "prefix_length" => 1,
                        'operator' => 'or'
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    "match" => [
                        "ean" => $this->builder->query,
                    ],
                ]
            ]
```